# ThemeData primaryColor not changing appBar background color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-theme

```dart
 class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
```

I am taking this course: https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-bootcamp-with-dart/

and with the section on themes she uses this exact code to turn her appBar red. My code does not display any errors, however my appBar remains the default theme.

The description of primary color here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

It doesn't say it is depreciated, or indicate any recent changes.

My question is not "how can I make my app bar red", but rather, "why does this code not perform as expected?"

Answer (score 7):

`PrimaryColor` won't work in `themeData` directly you have to declare it in `colorScheme`

```
theme: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.red)),
```

You can either use `primarySwatch`

```
theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
```

or you can use `appBarTheme`

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red
),
```

`primarySwatch` is not a Color. It's `MaterialColor`. Which means it's a the different shades of a color a material app will use.

`primaryColor` is one of those shades. To be exact, `primaryColor` is normally equal to `primarySwatch[500]`

`ThemeData` is one holding all of your theme settings, and the one controlling how the app will look, but `ColorScheme` is just a set of colors that you create to easily maintain the app's colors. Notice that `ThemeData` class has a parameter `colorScheme`, so you can create your own `colorScheme` and add it to the `ThemeData object`.

all of widgets styling inherits from colors or themes from `ThemeData` (defined in MaterialApp) not `ColorScheme`, `colorScheme` is just extra colors that you define to use whether in `ThemeData` or anywhere across the app.

Comment: Thank you. I have enough to move forward, but I have un unquenched curiosity about this subject. Is this a recent update? Is there any clear documentation on this change of syntax? Is primaryColor still listed as a property of theme data because it now does something else? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/primaryColor.html

Comment: I think `AppBar` can only accept `MaterialColor` rather than `Color` that's why it uses `primarySwatch` and not `primaryColor`, but I am not sure if it's because of this that `primaryColor` does not work, could you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: I have solved my problem, I actually had accomplished what i needed to before posting any of this. My inquiry is trying to deepen my knowledge on the matter. I appreciate all the input, there are now several ways I know of to work with theme and colors that work. My inquiry is an open one, I don't even know which question to ask. So here are some. I know some have good answers I can find here or elsewhere, I am not requesting direct answers, I just want to show where my mind is at with it.

Comment: What does the primaryColor property of theme data do?       Why were these changes made?      Why is scaffoldBackgroundColor a property of ThemeData instead of Color Scheme?       and of course, what is the difference between swatch color and material color? this last one is common enough to find, but I feel like the answer to it is intertwined with the answer to the others.

Comment: I have edited my answer with answers to your questions

Answer (score 2):

`AppBar` background color comes from `appBarTheme(color:..)`.

I prefer extending parent theme,

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  primaryColor: Colors.green,// no effect on AppBar
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
  ),
```

More about [theme](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme).

Answer (score 2):

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Color(0xFF090C22),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF090C22),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF090C22),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF090C22),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing the same course on udemy and using colorscheme as below worked for me. Primary color applied to appbar.

colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.red,secondary: Colors.white)